# Tensorflow Sparse Tensor operation too slow

Tags: tensorflow, scipy, tensorflow2.0, sparse-matrix, tensor

I'm trying to convert a scipy sparse matrix to Tensorflow Sparse Tensor using the code below:

```
coo = norm_adj_mat.tocoo().astype(np.float32)  ## norm_adj_mat is the scipy CSR matrix
indices = np.mat([coo.row, coo.col]).transpose()
A_tilde = tf.SparseTensor(indices, coo.data, coo.shape)
```

My original matrix is too large (>1 Million rows, cols) - the tensorflow conversion takes forever to convert it (>20 hours). I've tried it with a toy matrix and it seems to work fine for it. Any inputs on how to speed up this step?

I'm using tensorflow 2.9.1 & scipy 1.9.